# Convert character to html in R

Tags: html, r

What's the prefered way in R to convert a character (vector) containing non-ASCII characters to html? I would for example like to convert

```
  "ü"
```

to

```
  "&uuml;"
```

I am aware that this is possible by a clever use of `gsub` (but has anyone doen it once and for all?) and I thought that the package R2HTML would do that, but it doesn't.

EDIT: Here is what I ended up using; it can obviously be extended by modifying the dictionary:

```
char2html <- function(x){
  dictionary <- data.frame(
    symbol = c("ä","ö","ü","Ä", "Ö", "Ü", "ß"),
    html = c("&auml;","&ouml;", "&uuml;","&Auml;",
             "&Ouml;", "&Uuml;","&szlig;"))
  for(i in 1:dim(dictionary)[1]){
    x <- gsub(dictionary$symbol[i],dictionary$html[i],x)
  }
  x
}

x <- c("Buschwindröschen", "Weißdorn")
char2html(x)
```

Comment: It sounds like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060076/convert-html-character-entity-encoding-in-r might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yepp, that's the other way round :) I just checked the XML package: it has a `toHTML` function, but that does not solve the above question. It seems such a basic thing to do: every WYSIWYG html editor can do that.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you still need that in ages of UTF-8?

Comment: I am using a kind of content management system that only allows me to supply "pure" html, but some of my data is in UTF-8,

Comment: Is there an easy way to do the opposite of what your function is currently doing? I'd like to convert `"&uuml;"` to its respective character. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is pretty old but I couldn't find any straightforward answer... So I came up with this simple function which uses the numerical html codes and works for [LATIN 1 - Supplement](https://unicode-table.com/en/#latin-1-supplement) (integer values 161 to 255). There's probably (certainly?) a function in some package that does it more thoroughly, but what follows is probably good enough for many applications...

```
conv_latinsupp <- function(...) {
  out <- character()
  for (s in list(...)) {
    splitted <- unlist(strsplit(s, ""))
    intvalues <- utf8ToInt(enc2utf8(s))
    pos_to_modify <- which(intvalues >=161 & intvalues <= 255)
    splitted[pos_to_modify] <- paste0("&#0",  intvalues[pos_to_modify], ";")
    out <- c(out, paste0(splitted, collapse = ""))
  }
  out
}

conv_latinsupp("aeiou", "àéïôù12345")
## [1] "aeiou"   "&#0224;&#0233;&#0239;&#0244;&#0249;12345"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `XML` uses a method `insertEntities` for this, but that method is internal. So you may use it at your own risk, as there are no guarantees that it will remain to operate like this in future versions.

Right now, your code could be accomplished using

```
char2html <- function(x) XML:::insertEntities(x, c("ä"="auml", "ö"="ouml", …))
```

The use of a named list instead of a data.frame feels kind of elegant, but doesn't change the core of things. Under the hood, `insertEntities` calls `gsub` in much the same way your code does.

If numeric HTML entities are valid in your environment, then you could probably convert all your text into those using `utf8ToInt` and then turn safely printable ASCII characters back into unescaped form. This would save you the trouble of maintaining a dictionary for your entities.