# Convert default html encoding to UTF-8 or latin1 in R

Tags: html, r, character-encoding

I downloaded a web page with a list of Brazilian cities. The vector of strings come as follows

```
vector_cities = strsplit("Nova Lima,S&#227;o Paulo,Contagem,Rio de Janeiro,Rio de Janeiro,S&#227;o Paulo,Castanhal,Diadema,Rio de Janeiro,Rio Verde,Porto Alegre,Mauril&#226;ndia,Samambaia,Rio de Janeiro,Passo Fundo,S&#227;o Paulo,Casimiro de Abreu,Rio de Janeiro,Barueri,Santos,S&#227;o Paulo,S&#227;o Paulo,Goi&#226;nia,Pelotas,Rio de Janeiro", ",")

vector_cities
 [1] "Nova Lima"         "S&#227;o Paulo"    "Contagem"          "Rio de Janeiro"    "Rio de Janeiro"   
 [6] "S&#227;o Paulo"    "Castanhal"         "Diadema"           "Rio de Janeiro"    "Rio Verde"        
[11] "Porto Alegre"      "Mauril&#226;ndia"  "Samambaia"         "Rio de Janeiro"    "Passo Fundo"      
[16] "S&#227;o Paulo"    "Casimiro de Abreu" "Rio de Janeiro"    "Barueri"           "Santos"           
[21] "S&#227;o Paulo"    "S&#227;o Paulo"    "Goi&#226;nia"      "Pelotas"           "Rio de Janeiro"
```

I understand the coding of the above special characters, since this is the default encoding for html, however, I have tried many permutations of

```
iconv(vector_cities, from = "anything", to = "anything")
```

and they didn't return S(code)o = São or Sao, for example. Calling `Encoding(vector_cities)` results in the following

```
    [1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
[11] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
[21] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
```

What am I missing? Do I have to change something in the strings to get the right encoding?

Comment: this can help maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5060076/4137985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following, I have used `stringi` function and a custom function to convert html #& to unicode equivalent, a function called `stri_trans_general` from `stringi` helped me translate these unicode converted into english alphabets. I have taken the xml parser from [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060076/convert-html-character-entity-encoding-in-r) link on SO itself

```
library(stringi)
vector_cities = strsplit("Nova Lima,S&#227;o Paulo,Contagem,Rio de Janeiro,Rio de Janeiro,S&#227;o Paulo,Castanhal,Diadema,Rio de Janeiro,Rio Verde,Porto Alegre,Mauril&#226;ndia,Samambaia,Rio de Janeiro,Passo Fundo,S&#227;o Paulo,Casimiro de Abreu,Rio de Janeiro,Barueri,Santos,S&#227;o Paulo,S&#227;o Paulo,Goi&#226;nia,Pelotas,Rio de Janeiro", ",")

vector_cities <- vector_cities[[1]]

library(XML)

html_txt <- function(str) {
  xpathApply(htmlParse(str, asText=TRUE),
             "//body//text()", 
             xmlValue)[[1]] 
}

##The html_txt can parse the &#227 etc chars to their respective UTF values which can further be taken by stringi functions to convert into english alphabets

x <- vector_cities 
txt <- html_txt(x)
Encoding(txt) <- "UTF-8" #encoding to utf-8, It is optional you may avoid it
splt_txt <-strsplit(txt,split="\n")[[1]]
stringi::stri_trans_general(splt_txt, "latin-ascii")
```

**Output:**

```
 [1] "Nova Lima"         "Sao Paulo"        
 [3] "Contagem"          "Rio de Janeiro"   
 [5] "Rio de Janeiro"    "Sao Paulo"        
 [7] "Castanhal"         "Diadema"          
 [9] "Rio de Janeiro"    "Rio Verde"        
[11] "Porto Alegre"      "Maurilandia"      
[13] "Samambaia"         "Rio de Janeiro"   
[15] "Passo Fundo"       "Sao Paulo"        
[17] "Casimiro de Abreu" "Rio de Janeiro"   
[19] "Barueri"           "Santos"           
[21] "Sao Paulo"         "Sao Paulo"        
[23] "Goiania"           "Pelotas"          
[25] "Rio de Janeiro"
```

Comment: note: `iconv(sapply(vector_cities[[1]], html_txt), "UTF-8", "latin1")` also works if one does not want to load another package

Comment: @Cath Thanks for your input, however i am receiving a <e3> character instead of a for the second vector. However I got to know that using Encoding function is useless in this case, stringi also works without it.

Comment: strange, it works for me, probably different local settings