# Parse HTML/XML characters in R

Tags: r

I am reading in the following XML as a text file in R:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE score-partwise PUBLIC
    "-//Recordare//DTD MusicXML 3.0 Partwise//EN"
    "http://www.musicxml.org/dtds/partwise.dtd">
<score-partwise version="3.0">
  <part-list>
    <score-part id="P1">
      <part-name>Music</part-name>
    </score-part>
  </part-list>
  <part id="P1">
    <measure number="1">
      <attributes>
        <divisions>1</divisions>
        <key>
          <fifths>0</fifths>
        </key>
        <time>
          <beats>4</beats>
          <beat-type>4</beat-type>
        </time>
        <clef>
          <sign>G</sign>
          <line>2</line>
        </clef>
      </attributes>
      <note>
        <pitch>
          <step>C</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
        </pitch>
        <duration>4</duration>
        <type>whole</type>
      </note>
    </measure>
  </part>
</score-partwise>
```

R:

```
library(readtext)

xml <- readtext("musicxml.txt")$text
```

I am then trying to render this in Javascript via Shiny by feeding my XML text to a Javascript function. NB: Working outside of R.

```
shiny::tags$script(paste0('var osmd = new opensheetmusicdisplay.OpenSheetMusicDisplay(\"sheet-music\", {drawingParameters: "compact",
                drawPartNames: false, drawMeasureNumbers: false, drawMetronomeMarks: false, drawTitle: false});
                var loadPromise = osmd.load(\'',xml,'\');
                              loadPromise.then(function(){
                              osmd.render();
                              });
                              '))
```

However, when I concatenate the XML string above, it does not work because characters are escaped, e.g one line:

```
 &lt;note&gt;
```

I tried using the unescape_xml function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35187962) (with and without the  tags removed), but this does not solve the problem. It leaves me with:

```
"Music1044G2C44whole"
```

So how can I end up with a concatenated string with none of the escaped characters? It must just be a string and not another R object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the contents of the `tag` call with `shiny::HTML` to ensure it is passed unescaped:

```
shiny::tags$script(shiny::HTML(paste0(
'var osmd = new opensheetmusicdisplay.OpenSheetMusicDisplay(\"sheet-music\", 
{ drawingParameters: "compact",
  drawPartNames: false,  
  drawMeasureNumbers: false, 
  drawMetronomeMarks: false, 
  drawTitle: false});
 var loadPromise = osmd.load(\'',xml,'\');
 loadPromise.then(function(){ osmd.render() });')))
```

Which gives you:

```html
<script>var osmd = new opensheetmusicdisplay.OpenSheetMusicDisplay("sheet-music", 
{ drawingParameters: "compact",
  drawPartNames: false,  
  drawMeasureNumbers: false, 
  drawMetronomeMarks: false, 
  drawTitle: false});
 var loadPromise = osmd.load('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE score-partwise PUBLIC
    "-//Recordare//DTD MusicXML 3.0 Partwise//EN"
    "http://www.musicxml.org/dtds/partwise.dtd">
<score-partwise version="3.0">
  <part-list>
    <score-part id="P1">
      <part-name>Music</part-name>
    </score-part>
  </part-list>
  <part id="P1">
    <measure number="1">
      <attributes>
        <divisions>1</divisions>
        <key>
          <fifths>0</fifths>
        </key>
        <time>
          <beats>4</beats>
          <beat-type>4</beat-type>
        </time>
        <clef>
          <sign>G</sign>
          <line>2</line>
        </clef>
      </attributes>
      <note>
        <pitch>
          <step>C</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
        </pitch>
        <duration>4</duration>
        <type>whole</type>
      </note>
    </measure>
  </part>
</score-partwise>');
 loadPromise.then(function(){ osmd.render() });</script>
```

Comment: Ah nice, so simple! Thanks.