# How to subset html entities in a data frame in r?

Tags: html, r, select, subset

I have a data frame with several variables and thousands of rows. I have detected that in some rows there are some html entities like `"age(&gt;2Yr"` which means `"age>2Yr"`. This issue makes it hard to make sense of them without being decoded (please see here for more examples: https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp). I need to identify where in my data such html entities occur. There is a similar discussion on html entities ([convert HTML Character Entity Encoding in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060076/convert-html-character-entity-encoding-in-ru)) but it still does not answer my question because I do not want to convert these characters but just to identify them in my data. I would really appreciate your advice.