# Printing unicode hex characters

Tags: r, unicode

My data contains strings with unicode hex characters like [this character](https://www.codetable.net/hex/2013) "En Dash", basically a hyphen.

```
str = "foo &#x2013; bar"
```

Is there any way to make this print nicely in R, for example via `cat()`? I've tried a couple of unicode decoders to no effect.

Comment: Not a duplicate as far as I can tell because it's a completely different hex format. Maybe check your facts before closing whoever did that.

Comment: Use the `unescape_html` function from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060076/convert-html-character-entity-encoding-in-r

Comment: A very useful pointer thanks Herr Flick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [found](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2013) that the unicode of endash is `U+2013`

So you can use the unicode and cat to display the **endash** character

```r
message <-"foo \U2013 bar"

cat(message)
```

Comment: Thanks Liap. I suppose this is a manual workaround to convert the hex format.